# Calculate score by columns in r

Tags: r, loops, custom-function

I have a matrix with subjects as columns and each row is the answer of a question. I need to calculate the score of each subject and I wanted to create a loop. So, for the number of times each person said "Not at all" it multiplies by 0, for Several days it multiplies by 1 and so on and it adds it up to calculate a score of depression (a sum). It looks like this:

```
Person1       Person2        Person3
Not at all    Several days   Not at all
Several days  Several days   Several days
...
```

I tried:

```
scores1<-matrix(nrow=1,ncol=43)
x0<-1
seq<-as.vector(seq(x0,43,1))
seq<-paste0("V",seq)
colnames(scores1)=seq

for(x in colnames(t_dep_base)){
  a<-sum(str_count("Not at all"))*0
  b<-sum(str_count("Several days"))*1
  c<-sum(str_count("More than half the days"))*2
  d<-sum(str_count("Nearly every day"))*3
  suma_x<-a+b+c+d
  scores1[,suma_x]=seq
}
```

But it says the the subscript it's out of bounds. I would love to have something like:

```
Person1       Person2        Person3
4             0              1
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something along the lines of:

```r
# generating sample data:
values = c(
  "Not at all",
  "Several days",
  "More than half the days",
  "Nearly every day"
)

data = data.frame(
  Person1 = sample(values, size = 6, replace = T),
  Person2 = sample(values, size = 6, replace = T),
  Person3 = sample(values, size = 6, replace = T)
)
```

Solution:

```
mapping <- function(x){
  switch(x,
         "Not at all" = 0,
         "Several days" = 1,
         "More than half the days" = 2,
         "Nearly every day" = 3)
}

apply(data, 2, function(z){
  sum(sapply(z, mapping))
})
```